# Fluetter & SurveyKit - How to serialize SurveyResult to JSON

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have the following code:

```
return SurveyKit(
  onResult: (SurveyResult result) {
    print(result.finishReason);
  },
...
);
```

Do you know how to serialize `result.results` to a JSON file?

Thank you.

Comment: add the output of the result.finishReason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below would do the trick. It converts QueryResult questions and answers to JSON by iterating on every question and then every answer.

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> queryResultToJson(SurveyResult result) {
  return <String, dynamic>{
    "finishReason": result.finishReason.name,
    "steps": result.results
        .map((step) => <String, dynamic>{
              "id": step.id?.id,
              "startDate": step.startDate.toIso8601String(),
              "endDate": step.endDate.toIso8601String(),
              "results": step.results
                  .map((r) => <String, dynamic>{
                        "id": r.id?.id,
                        "result": r.result is BooleanResult
                            ? ((r.result as BooleanResult) == BooleanResult.POSITIVE
                                ? true
                                : (r.result as BooleanResult) == BooleanResult.NEGATIVE
                                    ? false
                                    : null)
                            : r.result is TimeOfDay
                                ? '${(r.result as TimeOfDay).hour}:${(r.result as TimeOfDay).minute}'
                                : r.result is DateTime
                                    ? (r.result as DateTime).toIso8601String()
                                    : r.result,
                        "startDate": r.startDate.toIso8601String(),
                        "endDate": r.endDate.toIso8601String(),
                        "valueIdentifier": r.valueIdentifier,
                      })
                  .toList()
            })
        .toList()
  };
}
```

And then, to convert it to `String`:

```dart
final json = queryResultToJson(result);
print(jsonEncode(json));
```

This is the result of running [the SurveyKit example code](https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/survey_kit/tree/e1f12bdfe71a0e2c8e34184eb6862cc8ebfdf0bf/example)

```json
{
  "finishReason": "COMPLETED",
  "steps": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:23:45.752352",
      "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:23:47.360266",
      "results": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "result": null,
          "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:23:45.752352",
          "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:23:47.360266",
          "valueIdentifier": "instruction"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:23:47.420516",
      "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:23:50.420628",
      "results": [
        {
          "id": "2",
          "result": 24,
          "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:23:47.420516",
          "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:23:50.420628",
          "valueIdentifier": "24"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:23:50.451292",
      "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:02.388185",
      "results": [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "result": true,
          "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:23:50.451292",
          "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:02.388185",
          "valueIdentifier": "Yes"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:02.413570",
      "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:05.266691",
      "results": [
        {
          "id": "4",
          "result": "asdf",
          "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:02.413570",
          "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:05.266691",
          "valueIdentifier": "asdf"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:05.286859",
      "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:06.176940",
      "results": [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "result": 3.0,
          "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:05.286859",
          "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:06.176940",
          "valueIdentifier": "3.0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:06.190944",
      "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:08.361066",
      "results": [
        {
          "id": "6",
          "result": [
            {
              "text": "Pet",
              "value": "Pet"
            }
          ],
          "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:06.190944",
          "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:08.361066",
          "valueIdentifier": "Pet"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:08.381213",
      "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:09.835139",
      "results": [
        {
          "id": "7",
          "result": {
            "text": "No",
            "value": "No"
          },
          "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:08.381213",
          "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:09.835139",
          "valueIdentifier": "No"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:09.861336",
      "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:10.975047",
      "results": [
        {
          "id": "8",
          "result": "12:0",
          "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:09.861336",
          "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:10.975047",
          "valueIdentifier": "TimeOfDay(12:00)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:11.006271",
      "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:11.933636",
      "results": [
        {
          "id": "9",
          "result": "2021-06-25T04:08:16.000Z",
          "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:11.006271",
          "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:11.933636",
          "valueIdentifier": "2021-06-25T04:08:16.000Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:23:45.753350",
      "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:14.027346",
      "results": [
        {
          "id": "10",
          "result": null,
          "startDate": "2022-06-28T16:23:45.753350",
          "endDate": "2022-06-28T16:24:14.027346",
          "valueIdentifier": "completion"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```